# Facing problems with creating a drop down that changes color based on condition imposed in Adobe Acrobat pro DC

Tags: adobe, acrobat, adobe-reader

I'm creating a form in Acrobat pro DC and have around 30 fields to put drop boxes into.

These drop boxes will change color according to condition I put on them. Options are "**Near**", "**Below**" and "**Achieved**".

These words are basically for sales targets. Now **red** is for "Below", **yellow** for "Near" and **green** for "Achieved".

I searched relevant threads and copy pasted the code in my own version, yet things don't seem to work out.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? Also, field names would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for reaching me out here. Sure. Give me a moment please.

Comment: if (event.value=="Near") 
event.target.fillColor = color.yellow; 
else if (event.value=="Below") 
event.target.fillColor = color.red; 
else if (event.value=="Achieved") 
event.target.fillColor = color.green; 
else event.target.fillColor = color.white;

Comment: Field names - Near, Below, Achieved

Comment: I also have a screenshot, how can I show it to you here?

Comment: Where are you putting that code?

Comment: Click the dropdown box- properties- validate- run custom JavaScript

Comment: Place the code and done. I found this code from an Adobe thread and I copy pasted the thing and made my own working version